# What will be my Primary and Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am newbie to Database: what will be my Primary and Foreign keys for the following database: 
user buys items and rates them by giving ratings(1,2,3,4,5)
  user(id, name)
  item(id, description, category, price) 
  buys(user, item, price)
  rates(user, item, rating)

Comment: What would be your approach? Can you add what your best guess would be?

Comment: primary key is usually id, because it is unique identifier, foreign key is dependant on what you have right now. like, if you have name set to varchar(255) and buys(user) is also varchar(255) then you can link them together with a FK constraint to have a user be associated with a product (just a guess don't quote me)

Comment: maybe try to do your own research on what PKs and FKs are... It's useful to know what they are instead of taking random peoples words

Comment: @L_Church "user" in "buys" should reference the ID in "user" table since "name" could change. Except if you want to explicitly save the name value of the user at the time of the buy. But even then, I'd have both fields because "name" may not be unique. Sunday: in "buys" and "rates" , I would add the date (or even datetime) when the entry was made.

Comment: this is why i never want people quoting me it'll screw em up if im not corrected lol

Answer (score 1):

**Primary key**

- id in User table
- id in item table

**Foreign key**

- user_id (referring User table PK) and item_id (referring item table PK) in buys table
- user_id (referring User table PK) and item_id (referring item table PK) rates table

Answer (score 0):

In the given situation acc. to me this is what you have to take following columns as:

### Primary Key:

```
Id in User table
Id in Item Table
```

### Foreign Key:

```
User in Buys Table Of ID in User Table
Item in Buys Table Of ID in Item Table
User in Rates Table Of ID in User Table
Item in Rates Table Of ID in Item Table
```

Comment: Now you gave a starving person a fish ... (better tell them how to catch one)

Comment: Great guys, pretty much the same, in workbench ,tables with no PK, could not be edited!!!!!Was read only

Answer (score 0):

PK = primary key
FK = foreign key

```
user(PK userid, name)

item(PK itemid, description, category, price) 

buys(FK userid, FK itemid, price) 

rates(FK userid, FK itemid, rating)
```

`buys` needs a price only if the price can change.

The user and item tables need a primary key so they can be referenced by the buys and rates tables. I used different names than `id` so it is clear which columns to join over when doing a select with a join operation.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you could lay out how you came to that solution.